# How do I change the following code to print the following output?

Tags: python-2.7

```
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(5):
        print i,
    print
```

Desired Output:

```
1
2 1
3 2 1
4 3 2 1
```

I am a little hazy on how the loop works, so if someone could provide a detailed explanation of the correct code, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,5):
    aux = i
    for j in range(i):
        print aux,
        aux=aux-1
    print
```

[DEMO HERE](http://codepad.org/Qo1KpiZK)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

```
for i in xrange(1,5):
    for j in xrange(i, 0, -1):
        print j,
    print
```

---

In your code, in each iteration, you print the same number again and again:

```
for j in range(5):
        print i,
```

but expect that every number in the row will be different... Not a big surprise it doesn't work.